# ASP.NET MVC relative path for a jQuery spinner image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, path, spinner

In an ASP.NET MVC project I'm trying to use [jQuery spinner plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Spinner). All's working fine except the following problem: an animated `spinner.gif` is shown only if I use an absolute path to the image as a custom parameter.

In a `jquery.spinner.js` script file the default path to the image is just plain "spinner.gif". I tried to put the image to the Image folder, which is inside Content folder, to the Script folder itself, to the root of the application folder - nothing was shown.

Where I should put the image in this case or how should I define the relative path, or maybe it's the issue specific to the ASP.NET MVC routing approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the script executes, it will look for the resource **relative to where the current page is**, not where the script resides.

If you have the image in your `/Content/` folder then you can change the `img src` to something like `../../Content/image.gif` where the `../` will send you back up a directory.

Answer (score -1):

You should correct the `jquery.spinner.js` to use relative path to animated file. Either just place file near javascript code (but this not good option).

Comment: I tried to put a copy of the image to the same folder as the script itself, it's the "Script" folder. No success.